# how can we apply the formula p=VI in power transmission lines?

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-engineering

i mean we don't know the value of voltage across the power lines...we just know the potential at which it is generated which is not the potential difference across its ends..say electricity is generated at 11,000 V...this is the potential and not the potential difference...so we cant apply p=vi

Comment: I recommend that you try asking your questions here:  http://electronics.stackexchange.com/  Primarily due to the fact that there is a built in schematic editor that will greatly aid in asking and answering questions of this type.

Answer (score 0):

This is a potential difference. In power transmission, it's the RMS amplitude of a alternating signal.